# Extract specified area from DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

i want to manipulate the following cvs file:

```
"Day" "Hour" "X1" "X2" "X3" "X4" "X5"
2015-01-01 00:00 1 2 3 4 5
         .....
```

to the following:

```
"Day Hour" "X2" "X3" "X5"
"2015-01-01 00:00" 2 3 5
         .....
```

It's just combine two columns and use a range of columns.
Ive tried to following:

```
csv = pandas.read_csv('test.csv')
csv['Time'] = cvs.Day + " " + csv.Hour
csv.set_index('Time')
```

I can not figure out how to get this columns without creating a new DataFrame.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reassign csv to a new dataframe:

```
df['Time'] = df.Day + " " + df.Hour

df = df[[-1]]
```

Once you have no other reference to the df then it will be gc'd

Or use the `csv` lib to read and join the columns after zipping with transposing with `itertools.izip` :

```
import pandas as pd
from itertools import izip
import csv

with open("foo.csv") as f:
    next(f) # skip header
    r = csv.reader(f)
    zp = izip(*r)
    pairs = izip(next(zp), next(zp))
    df = pd.DataFrame(("{} {}".format(a,b) for a,b in pairs),columns=["Time"])

    print(df)
```

Output:

```
              Time
0  2015-01-01 00:00
```

If you actually want to keep the other columns just drop after creating the new column:

```
df['Time'] = df.Day + " " + df.Hour

df.drop(["Day","Hour"],axis=1,inplace=True)
print(df)
```

Comment: and how can i select X2-X3 and X5 ?

Comment: @Roby, are you trying to join the first two and keep all the rest or just create a df from the first two?

Comment: i want to create a new data frame, with the merged Time column and specified columns ( range and name selection)

Answer (score 0):

The simplest answer has really nothing to do with csv. Your sample text is not comma-separated. So, given your shown format, here's a solution.  The last three lines could be combined into one, but I've elected to keep them separate for clarity.

```
import string
with open('test.csv') as f:
    for line in f:
        line = line.strip().split(' ')
        line = line[0:2] + line[3:5] + line[6:7]
        print string.join(line, ' ')
```

If the lines really were in csv format, you'd just change the arguments for split and join above from ' ' to ','.